# Replacing data values based on grep result in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame. One of the columns has values like:

> WIND
>   WINDS
>   HIGH WIND
>   etc

among the other values. Now I want to rename every value that has some variation of "WIND" in it, with "WIND". I know how to find values that I need to replace:

```
grep("WIND", df$col1)
```

but not how to replace those values. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just subset the original column for these values by using grepl and replace

```
df$col1[grepl("WIND",df$col1)]<-"WIND"
```

Comment: Note if you're going to do this you can just use `grep` as it returns the indices, which works (and is actually a little faster, though that rarely matters).

Comment: up-boats for you sir!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** a bit of a brainfart, `agrep` actually doesn't add anything here over grep, but you can just replace the `agrep` with `grep`.  It does if you have some words that have roots that vary slightly but you still want to match.

Here is an approach using `agrep`:

```
> wind.vec
[1] "WINDS"      "HIGH WIND"  "WINDY"      "VERY WINDY"
> wind.vec[agrep("WIND", wind.vec)] <- "WIND"
> wind.vec
[1] "WIND" "WIND" "WIND" "WIND"
```

The nice thing about `agrep` is it matches approximately, so "WINDY" is replaced.  Note I'm doing this with a vector, but you can easily extend to a data frame by replacing `wind.vec` with `my.data.frame$my.wind.col`.

`agrep` returns the indices that match approximately, which then allows me to use the `[<-` replacement operator to replace the approximately matching values with "WIND".