# Deleting all apostrophes in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I was just wondering if there was a way to delete the apostrophes in all of the cells in a data frame in R.  I have tried adding using lapply, and apply to achieve this but nothing has worked so far.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). As your question now stands it is way too broad. Try to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
df2 <-  as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) gsub("'", "", x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[,i] <- gsub("'","",df[,i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching and replacement is easily done with the grep functions:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html

A simple example:

```
z <- c("A'", "B", "C'")
x <- c("D", "E", "F'")
D <- data.frame(z, x)
D$z <- gsub("'", "", D$z)
D$x <- gsub("'", "", D$x)
```

This post provides another implementation example:
[Replacing data values based on grep result in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100958/replacing-data-values-based-on-grep-result-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

My data frame below:

```
 my_df=data.frame(a=c("a'a","b"),b=c("c","d'd"))
 my_df
 #     a   b
 # 1 a'a   c
 # 2 b   d'd

 result=as.data.frame(lapply(my_df,gsub,pattern="'",replacement=""))
 result
 #   a   b
 # 1 aa  c
 # 2 b  dd
```

Hope this helped. Thank you.